# TPL How to Correctly Cancel a Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, cancellation

I have the following task

```
cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
token = cancelSource.Token;

string strDbA = textBox1.Text;
string strDbB = textBox2.Text;

// Start duplication on seperate thread. 
asyncDupSqlProcs =
    new Task<bool>(state =>
        UtilsDB.DuplicateSqlProcsFrom(token, mainForm.mainConnection, strDbA, strDbB), "Duplicating SQL Proceedures");
asyncDupSqlProcs.Start();
asyncDupSqlProcs.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    switch (task.Status)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
            // Error-handling logic...
            break;
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            if (asyncDupSqlProcs.Result)
                Utils.InfoMsg(String.Format(
        "SQL stored procedures and functions successfully copied from '{0}' " + 
                    "to '{1}'", strDbA, strDbB));
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Canceled:
            Utils.InfoMsg("Copy cancelled at users request.");
            break;
    }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

In the method `DuplicateSqlProcsFrom(token, mainForm.mainConnection, strDbA, strDbB)` I have the standard cancellation detection:

```
if (_token.IsCancellationRequested)
    _token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

The cancellation event is a button click on the main form, inside the click event I have:

```
try
{
    cancelSource.Cancel();
    asyncDupSqlProcs.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException aggEx)
{
    if (aggEx.InnerException is OperationCanceledException)
        Utils.InfoMsg("Copy cancelled at users request.");
}
```

but I can seem to catch the `AggregateException`, what am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Inside the method `DuplicateSqlProcsFrom(token, mainForm.mainConnection, strDbA, strDbB)` I can catch the `OperationCancelledException` but I am confused about how to handle it. All the example I have seen handle the printing of "Operation Cancelled..." etc. on the UI thread within the event that caused the cancel. What is the best way to capture the cancel and pass it back to the UI/calling thread?

Comment: What is the exception being thrown that is not being handled?

Comment: Hmmm, I get the exception actually on my test code.  Are you sure the method DuplicateSqlProcsFrom() isn't exiting fast?

Comment: Also what context is this getting kicked off from?  another thread?  The UI thread?

Comment: Inside the method that contains the `if (_token.IsCancellationRequested)` it throws the `OperationCancelException`, fine. But what do I do with it? It is being caught on the new (background) thread, but I am unsure how to deal with it in the last `try`/`catch` block?

Comment: Sorry that was not clear. I'll edit the question...

Comment: It is being launched from the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an `OperationCancelledException`, it needs to be thrown with the same token as the one passed to the Task's constructor:

```
new Task<bool>(state =>
    UtilsDB.DuplicateSqlProcsFrom(token, mainForm.mainConnection, strDbA, strDbB),
        "Duplicating SQL Proceedures", token);
```

Answer (score 2):

It most likely has to do with Just My Code mode (defaulted to checked) in Visual Studio.  The debugger is breaking before the TPL can observe the exception.  Try unchecking the box and see if that clears things up (Tools->Options->Debugging->General, then un-check the box)